# CPU Fan not working properly?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling, temperature

Recently I just built my own computer. However the temperature of my processor becomes very high and my CPU fan is not able to cool it off when I run multiple programs.

MY CPU temperature can go as high as 85 degrees celsius and it is definitely not good. My CPU fan speed can go as high as 2419rpm only at 100%. I believe normal CPU fans are supposed to run faster than this at 100%.

I have just bought the i7-3770K processor from Intel (Less than half a year) and can I claim the warranty if the fan is faulty? Is this normal and I should buy a better CPU fan?

Comment: Probably the thermal paste. Did you apply it yourself?

Comment: 85C at peak load with stock clocking, stock voltage, and stock cooler is perfectly normal, assuming you're talking about the die/core temperature, not the spreader temperature. The CPU has Turbo Boost 2.0 and will raise its clock speed if it's not overheating. The die doesn't overheat until about 97C. (The case overheats at 68C)

Comment: Perhaps you should invest in a decent CPU cooling solution, stock coolers are pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, 2000 rpm is quite normal. My PC fan goes around 1500 rpm.

The problem might be that the fan isn't installed properly, or the thermal paste is too thin/thick, or some other problems.

Comment: the thermal paste comes with the heat sink, there is no need for me to apply. Is it I have to buy extra thermal paste and apply on it?

Comment: Of course that thermal paste comes with heat sink/fan. So, you may not have to apply it by yourself. Then it must be something about the fan no contacting your CPU properly. I had a 775 cpu years ago, it runs at 50C idle, i thought that was good until I install the fan properly and apply some more thermal paste. It goes 36C idle.

Comment: Okay, ideally my CPU runs at 46C with CPU fan speed of 1413. I have checked and the fan is tightly installed. It may be of lack of thermal paste, will buy some and apply see if it helps..

Comment: no overclock right?

Comment: Nope, no overclock.

Comment: Hi I just change the thermal paste and my CPU temperature is still high, about 80C. I don't think the temperature is normal as my motherboard keep giving me warning sign that my CPU temperature is too high. Could it be other thing other than the thermal paste?

Comment: Please try to measure your temperature again using Real Temp or Core Temp. People say Real Temp is better, but I personally prefer Core Temp. Also, how do you define full load? Games? Or burning in with Prime95 or something similar?

Comment: If you're getting 80+ when burning in, that's perfectly normal. I wouldn't worry too much. But if it occurs with games, it's probably something to worry about.

Comment: Also, you can get a better CPU fan quite cheap. As you won't do overclock, water-cooling might be an overkill. But it sure is fun, and will keep your whole CPU cool. It's a bit more expensive and complicated to setup, but it's definitely worth it. I am quite happy with my water-cooling gears now.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience 2419 rpm is normal. My CPU fan works at an average of 1000 rpm, with a max point of 1500 rpm. 
I noticed that others also stated that it might be due to thermal paste as you mentioned in the comments that it did not solve your problem.
Maybe the problem is still the fan. Just because it has a high speed does not make it a good fan all the time. Hence I suggest investing in a better CPU fan.
Also, I suggest you make sure the air flow is good around the PC. If you have something blocking the airflow, the fan might not be able to do its job.